# ignore: ":hidden" does not work for controls with display:none

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I am using jquery validation to validate my aspx page. `deliveryToDiv` is hidden by setting

```
document.getElementById("deliveryToDiv").style.display = "none";
```

This div has other controls which will be validated depending on this div's visibility.
But setting `ignore:"hidden"` does not appear to work on this div. The error message is thrown even if this div not visible. How can I detect if this div is visible and perform validation?

What is the workaround? please advise.Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean `ignore: ":hidden"`, with a leading colon?

Comment: If I am not wrong, ignore:"hidden" is used for input type hidden.

Comment: are you using html controls or ASP.net controls

Comment: @GaneshPandhere: is it? nowhere I found this info

Comment: use `$("#elem").hide();`

Comment: @Avinash: the div i am refering to is html div

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: thanks. i have missed leading colon. will give a try

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ignore:":hidden" did the trick. Would you mind posting your comment as answer? I can mark it as answer. thank you.

Comment: Which version of jQuery Validate?  As of 1.9.0, all hidden elements are ignored by default... no need to use the `ignore` option.  You're just over-riding this default by using `ignore`.  See:  http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/

Comment: Then you don't need the `ignore` option at all.  Remove it and everything will work as you've requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ignore` option takes a selector, and the [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector starts with a colon character.

Therefore, you should write:

```
ignore: ":hidden"
```

Instead of:

```
ignore: "hidden"
```

The latter matches `<hidden>` elements instead of elements that are not visible.

Comment: Should be noted that ignoring all hidden input elements is now the default behavior in v 1.9+.  http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/ ~ _"...Another change should make the setup of forms with hidden elements easier, these are now ignored by default (option `ignore` has `:hidden` now as default)."_

Answer (score 1):

`:hidden` is for `<input type="hidden">`. So maybe if you disable all fields in your div it will help. Validation should skip disabled fields.

Comment: strange, the div I am refering to in not a hidden field, but still ignore:":hidden" works for me.

Comment: yes, you are right, just tested it and that works too. Looks like problem is in wrong value `ignore` as in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`How can I detect if this div is visible and perform validation?`

to do this you can follow like this:

```
if($('#deliveryToDiv').is(':visible')){
   // do the validation here
}else{
   // do the other stuff if not visible
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The possible reason can be that there is `ignore: ':hidden'` line in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file`. Just remove that line.

After 1.9.0 version it was default behaviour. If the line doesn't exists in file(I'm not sure) you can fix that manually by adding

`$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });`

As you can see here

Another change should make the setup of forms with hidden elements easier, these are now ignored by default (option “ignore” has “:hidden” now as default). In theory, this could break an existing setup. In the unlikely case that it actually does, you can fix it by setting the ignore-option to “[]” (square brackets without the quotes).

Comment: You are only half correct.  Yes, in version 1.9.0, ignoring hidden elements became a default behavior.  However, setting the `ignore: []` option will **disable** that feature so it will **enable** validation for hidden fields.